# Is using a Trigger to Insert a new Record into a View seen as bad practice?

Tags: t-sql, best-practices

So I was recently having a conversation with one of my new work colleagues and we got onto the topic of how best to `INSERT` data into multiple tables.

Their teaching taught them to not use a `TRIGGER` to split an `INSERT` onto a `VIEW` into multiple `INSERTS` into their respective tables, is this seen as bad practice?

Following is how I attempted to solve the `INSERT` issue without creation of duplicate values in the base tables.

VIEW

```
CREATE VIEW [Person].[vPeopleAllInformation] AS
SELECT pt.Type_Name AS Type,
p.Firstname,
p.Lastname,
e.Email AS Email,
ph.Number AS PhoneNumber
FROM [Person].[People] p
FULL JOIN [Person].[Person_Types] pt ON p.Person_Type = pt.Person_Type_ID
FULL JOIN [Person].[Person_Emails] e ON e.Person_ID = p.Person_ID
FULL JOIN [Person].[Person_Phones] ph ON ph.Person_ID = p.Person_ID
```

TRIGGER

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Person].[tPerson_Email_Phone] ON [Person].[vPeopleAllInformation]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [Person].[People] (Person_Type, Firstname, Lastname)
SELECT p.Person_Type_ID, i.Firstname, i.Lastname FROM INSERTED i
INNER JOIN [Person].[Person_Types] p ON i.Type = p.Type_Name
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Person].[People] WHERE Firstname = i.Firstname AND Lastname = i.Lastname);

INSERT INTO [Person].[Person_Emails] (Person_ID, Email)
SELECT p.Person_ID, i.Email FROM INSERTED i
INNER JOIN [Person].[People] p ON p.FullName = CONCAT(i.Lastname, ', ', i.Firstname)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Person].[Person_Emails] WHERE Email = i.Email);

INSERT INTO [Person].[Person_Phones] (Person_ID, Number)
SELECT p.Person_ID, i.PhoneNumber FROM INSERTED i
INNER JOIN [Person].[People] p ON p.FullName = CONCAT(i.Lastname, ', ', i.Firstname)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Person].[Person_Phones] WHERE Number = i.PhoneNumber);

END
```

Is this the right way of doing it or should I indeed split it into multiple queries when the user attempts to add another Record to the view?

Comment: I would always use separate queries.  The biggest problem with triggers is that they are silently changing things in the background.  Occasionally that's what you need but mostly it just means that future work on the database causes a lot of unforseen/hidden consequences.  Triggers should be used sparingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

> ***No**, don't do that.*

**Longer answer:**

What problem are you trying to solve? It seems like maybe it's "*I would like to update multiple base tables with a single `INSERT` tsql command.*" If that's the case, then... Sure? I guess? Why not? As long as you accept that the scope of the implementation in question to do is pretty limited and clunky. You're really just obfuscating away the multiple steps you need to perform anyway. But what happens when you want to `DELETE` from that view? Or `UPDATE` from that view? Do you need other triggers to handle those cases?

At a minimum, if you're commited to trying it out for yourself and discovering the "*why nots*" on your own, I'd at least recommend modularizing out the separate `INSERT` statements in that trigger into their own procs. At least then you can reuse `spInsertPerson 1, 'Bob', 'Smith'` when all you really want to do is insert Bob Smith without mucking about with other side-effecting executions.

Still... I probably wouldn't...

Comment: I see what you mean with the modularizing of the queries, something similar to when i did general Game Development where I would make modular functions. But I see more where you start the update and delete comment "What happens if I only need to update the email of the person" or "Oh I suddenly want to delete that Phone Number" as well as if i have multiple different emails and phones per person which would it effect. Thanks for the feedback.